# JQuery accordion won't bring back default panel

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

This is not a jQuery UI accordion, just a show/hide script.
It is a list of links that are supposed to toggle divs with corresponding anchors.

My problem is that the first link and initial div, which displays by default, won't come back after it has been hidden. This is my javascript:

```
$('.active').click(function() {
    return false;
});
$('.ready').click(function() { 
    var accordionid = $(this).attr("href");

    // links are either 'active' or 'ready' 
    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('ready');
    $(this).removeClass('ready').addClass('active');

    // panels are have class 'showing' if they display
    $('.showing').slideToggle().removeClass('showing');
    $(accordionid).slideToggle().addClass('showing');  
    return false;
});
```

I have a fiddle here that shows my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/g0e00L2p/

I'd expect this script to only fire on links that have the 'ready' class. But for some reason it also fires on links that have the 'active' class.

Answer (score 2):

Since you weren't using event delegation to monitor changes to the DOM (commonly done via the on() method), jQuery only knew of your elements as it saw them on initial page load. It wasn't aware that the classes had changed from the perspective of the click function, which is a static object.

All that class toggling can be eliminated. jQuery does that for you.

```
$('#accordion li a').click(function (e) {
    var accordionid = $(this).attr("href");

    $('.resume-content').not(accordionid).slideUp();
    $(accordionid).slideDown();

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/g0e00L2p/6)

Note that I added an overflow statement to the CSS to eliminate the slide jump.

Comment: I assumed he had a reason for the classes. He may be doing something with CSS.

Comment: You may be right, but I've seen quite a few novice programmers do this when it's not necessary.

Comment: True. +1 for the `overflow` fix!

Comment: Ah, thank you, isherwood! Is the overflow statement the .preventDefault line?  Somehow I thought that was the same as return false.

Comment: Thank, guys. Both of these solutions solve my problem. 

But I still don't understand why. If my script was checking for links with .ready, why did it hit on links that did not have .ready? And the 'Bio' link, which was the default panel, did have .ready, but the script did not fire.

Comment: Further explanation added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You only have jQuery checking for `.ready` instead of checking **all** of the links. So I would do this:

#### HTML

Add class `tabs_list` to the `<ul>`:

```
<ul class="tabs_list"> 
    <li><a href="#biography" class="active">biography</a></li>
    <li><a href="#activities" class="ready">Professional Activities</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#admissions" class="ready">Bar Associations</a></li> 
</ul>
```

#### jQuery

And check **all** `<a>` descendents of `.tabs_list`. When `.ready` is clicked, make sure everyone turns `.ready`, not just anyone who is `.active`, but then make `$(this)` `.active`. Make sense?

```
$('.tabs_list a').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('ready')) {
        $('.tabs_list a').removeClass('active').addClass('ready');
        $(this).removeClass('ready').addClass('active');

        var accordionid = $(this).attr("href");
        $('.showing').slideToggle().removeClass('showing');
        $(accordionid).slideToggle().addClass('showing')
    }
    return false;
});
```

Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/70s6wtqg/1/)